# While running jest tests, coverage fails with Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, ts-jest

I'm trying to get jest tests to work in my project. I'm new to jest tests and it's my first setup.

The tests seem to pass but coverage fails.

I'm getting the following error when doing `yarn test`:

```
ERROR: C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\src\App.tsx: Unexpected token (27:20)

  25 |     switch (view) {
  26 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Home:
> 27 |             return (<HomePage_1.default />);
     |                     ^
  28 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Login:
  29 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Register:
  30 |             return (<LoginPage_1.default />);
STACK: SyntaxError: C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\src\App.tsx: Unexpected token (27:20)

  25 |     switch (view) {
  26 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Home:
> 27 |             return (<HomePage_1.default />);
     |                     ^
  28 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Login:
  29 |         case MainReducerSlice_1.ViewShown.Register:
  30 |             return (<LoginPage_1.default />);
    at Parser.raise (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6975:17)
    at Parser.unexpected (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8368:16)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9627:20)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9210:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9190:21)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9056:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9029:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8975:21)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9765:28)      
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9548:21)
Failed to collect coverage from C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\src\component\home-page\HomePage.tsx
ERROR: C:\Users\elico\Documents\React workspace\pi-preperation\src\component\home-page\HomePage.tsx: Unexpected token (32:12)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same issue. As I investigated, it was cause by my `tsconfig` 
The line `jsx:"preserve"` mean, that your TSX will be compiled to JSX, but Jest does not understand JSX w/o and preprocessing

```js
compilerOptions:{
//...
    "jsx": "preserve"
}
```

The correct config is

```js
compilerOptions:{
//...
    "jsx": "react"
}
```